# Shopify Template - Color Swatches using links not variants

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm currently working on a Shopify project and I need to add `color swatches` on the product pages. I already did it in other projects using the `product variants`. But in this case the colors are different products. I found some examples on shopify:

- [Fashion Nova](https://www.fashionnova.com/collections/mens-bottoms/products/retro-track-pant-black).
- [doyoueven](https://www.doyoueven.com/products/dye-seamless-low-line-crop-black).

In those examples when you click on a color you want, it changes the page. In the code it's a simple html link to the other products.

These brands are maybe using an app but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did some test and I came up with an idea. I still need to work on it but I think maybe it could be a solution.

I am using tags to linked the products together. I need to test with more product how it's working but it could be a good start.

```
<div class="swatches">
  <label>Colors</label>
  <br />
  <div class="related-colors">
    {% for relatedProduct in collections.all.products %}
      {% if product.tags contains relatedProduct.handle %} 
          {% for tag in relatedProduct.tags %}
              {% if tag contains 'color-' %}
                  {% assign color = tag | replace: 'color-', '' %}
                  <a href="{{ relatedProduct.url }}">
                    <div class="color-swatches" style="background-color: {{color}}"></div>
                  </a>
              {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>



<style>
  .swatches{
    width:100%;
    padding-left:5px;
  }
  .color-swatches 
  {
    margin-top:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: only problem with tag based solutions is polluting the tag space. You use them for custom logic, you have to include custom logic to ignore the custom logic for each case of custom logic. never ends does it.

Answer (score 0):

I did that with an App for a swim suit company. Due to the way their navigation worked, it was clear they had a product per color. Not a color per variant. The App I provided them was for curated links. So they could connect all the same products with the different colors, and easily provide clickable links to each, making for a super easy way to manage inventory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did you use an app on the market of did you create an app on your own ?

Comment: I always write my own. It works better that way. No worries about quality or features.